# Request for user script to remove mask from posts deleted as spam or offensive

Tags: discussion, posts, script-request, 10k-tools

As a contributor to Charcoal, I often find that the spam and offensive mask (i.e. "this post was deleted as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown, see the revision history") just *gets in my way* at times.

Can I please get a user script that removes this mask, and makes the spam post show on the page as if the masking feature didn't exist?

Comment: If anyone needs a spam post for testing, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020449) post is quite likely to have been deleted as spam.

Comment: Only 10K users would be able to use this feature  unless, *maybe*, the original body can be pulled from Metasmoke?

Comment: @BrockAdams There is an upvote now. I think it's fine for use by >10k users only, since they're the only ones who run into the masked spam message. In Charcoal, other users can see the post source on metasmoke; it's only if the user wants additional context that they'd actually click on the post (which does happen with me from time to time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've written a simple script for this, called **NSFW** (because it shows content that is Not Suitable For Work). It will only work if you have 10k reputation (2k on beta sites); otherwise, you probably won't see the post anyway. The link to the revision history will be added to the 'post menu' with the share, edit and flag links.

You can **install it [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/nsfw/nsfw.user.js)** (directly from GitHub).
Source code is [here](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/blob/master/nsfw/nsfw.user.js).

Developed and tested with Violentmonkey on Firefox, but should work on other browsers/monkey as well.

### Known issues

- Posts containing [code snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) will have those snippets show as plain code text and not as a runnable snippet.
- Due to [SE changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388600/red-flagged-question-titles-are-no-longer-shown-to-moderators#comment1296176_388600), this script does not currently work on the international sites (sites whose UI is in a language other than English).

### Screenshot

You can see it in action in the screenshot below (behind a spoiler, it's NSFW after all…)

> [image]

Comment: Works on Tampermonkey on Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Bug: Code snippets don't properly show up. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317287 for example. It just shows as normal code, not as a snippet.

Comment: @gparyani, That's [a Stack Exchange thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUDyR.jpg). You can post an FR on Meta, if you are feeling frisky.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that was some kind of precaution for malicious scripts, but the buttons do work on the revision page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/317287/1

Comment: @Glorfindel, yes and notice that [the inline code ***is*** grayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUDyR.jpg), so the formatting is not at all consistent.